# How to use query builder LIKE to Mapped Class

Tags: symfony, doctrine, sql-like, query-builder

I have `ContactPerson` and `TypeContact` classes.

```
class ContactPerson
{
     ...
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\MyBundle\Entity\TypeContact", inversedBy="type")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $typeContact;

    ...
}
```

and

```
class TypeContact
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
      private $name;
    ...
}
```

and my QueryBuilder like this

```
$typeContact= ...('MyBundle:TypeContact')->find($id);
$person = $repository->createQueryBuilder('person')
                     ->where('person.typeContact LIKE ?1')
                     ->setParameter(1, '%'.$typeContact.'%')
                     ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

But I get error message. 
How use LIKE for entity?
I use Symfony 2.6

Comment: If you are trying to get persons with contact_type id = 1. You don't have to use LIKE

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do like directly on an entity.

Assuming it's the name property of TypeContact you want to do the like on, something like this:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

$typeContacts = $qb->select('tc, cp')
    ->from('YourBundle:TypeContact', 'tc')
    ->join('tc.contactPerson', 'cp')
    ->where($qb->expr()->like('tc.name', $qb->expr()->literal('%YourStringHere%')))
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Otherwise you can only really match on entity id as so:

```
$typeContact = $qb->select('tc, cp')
    ->from('YourBundle:TypeContact', 'tc')
    ->join('tc.contactPerson', 'cp')
    ->where($qb->expr()->eq('tc', ':typeContact'))
    ->setParameter('typeContact', $yourTypeContactEntity)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I solved.

```
$typeContact= ...('MyBundle:TypeContact')->find($id);
$person = $repository->createQueryBuilder('person')
          ->join('person.typeContact', 'tp')
          ->where('tp.name LIKE ?1')
          ->setParameter(1, '%'.$typeContact->getName().'%')
          ->getQuery()
          ->getResult();
```